# Why do bind() and accept() let you specify the size of the struct?

Tags: sockets, networking, network-programming

bind() and accept() let you specify the size of the struct in the 2nd parameter. But I've only seen the size of the whole struct being passed. Why do they make you specify the size? Are there any instances where you would use a different number?

Comment: unix domain sockets versus tcp sockets versus ...

Answer (score 3):

Different socket protocol families use different types of structures.  For example, TCP and UDP sockets using IPv4 addresses utilize a `sockaddr_in` structure, which is 16 bytes in size, whereas IPv6 addresses utilize a `sockaddr_in6` structure instead, which is 28 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

The size of the `sockaddr` struct can vary, for instance depending on if you use IPv4 or IPv6.

Answer (score 1):

The size is specified because these are system calls, which execute in kernel mode and the kernel's address space, and the kernel doesn't otherwise know how much data to copy between kernel address space and user address space. It can't see for example whether you are using an IPv4 or IPv6 address structure.

Answer (score 0):

The size could depend on the implementation, the type of socket and/or platform. So if you pass this size with the call the same code would work on different platforms, no matter what extra fields or padding is used.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to historical reasons: poor man's function overloading to accept different types of socket addresses, like IPv4, UNIX, IPv6. See [page 68 of UNIX Network Programming: The sockets networking API](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=ptSC4LpwGA0C&lpg=PA68&ots=Kr3yRnipNn&dq=%22The%20length%20member%2C%20sin_len%2C%20was%20added%20with%204.3BSD-Reno%22&pg=PA68#v=onepage&q&f=false) for more details.